# In Flutter, bottomSheetDialog's radius is not working

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

To implement flutter bottomSheetDialog with dynamic height, I wrote a code like this.

```
void showCustomBottomSheetDialog(Widget body, BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        return Wrap(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 24.sp,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body,
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

```
showCustomBottomSheetDialog(
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(),
                      Text('asdfasdfds'),
                      Text('asdfasdfds'),
                      Text('asdfasdfds'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                context,
              );
```

But with this code, the displayed bottomSheet did not have a rounded corner...

Could you tell me what is a problem of my code...?

Comment: you have to make it manually , by default, the corner is not rounded

Comment: And change "now" to "not" in the title.... right? 

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Oh it is a typo :)

Comment: ...Probably a "typo"... but hey. It's late, right! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create rounded corner manually
eg:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (contex) {
    return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius:
                      const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(18))),
              child: Column(
                children: []
....
```

also you can wrap it with `DraggableScrollableSheet` to make it scrollable widget

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Container` with rounded corner is inside the `Column` widget.
For this to work ,lift up the `Container`.

Code now:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(...)
         ),
  },
);
```

Comment: OH your answer is same with @pmatatias's one! Thank you so much, too

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we have `shape` property on `showModalBottomSheet` and can be used to make rounded corner, like

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(  //this
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
      topRight: Radius.circular(24),
    ),
  ),
```

More about [`showModalBottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        enableDrag: false,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SizedBox(
              //70 percent of the screen
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.sp),
                  child: Container(color: Colors.red)));
        });
```